# PHP - Is it fine to use header() to redirect to a folder?

Tags: php

So i'm planning to to redirect users to a folder like this:

```
header('Location: folderName');
```

So would that work, and is it practical to do this?

Comment: If folderName works as an URL it would probably work. I.e. if it is a subfolder of the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should work and the webserver will search for another index.html or index.php and some more.

Answer (score 0):

It would work.  Just make sure you don't send out the page headers